# iOS StoreKit - simulating incomplete and interrupted in-app purchases

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, sandbox, storekit

I have an issue with a live app where incomplete purchases are being mishandled. I am trying to test my new code to make sure that this will be taken care of, so I download the live app, cause the problem, then load my development app (or Ad-Hoc app) hoping that the StoreKit Observer will catch the incomplete purchase notification. No matter how I do this (development or Ad-Hoc) the observer does not fire a notification.

My general question is: How can I simulate incomplete and interrupted purchases in the App Store testing environment?

My more specific question is: Can I simulate the specific issue where the user must leave the app to confirm their current credit card pin number on the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this helpful page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html):

> Test an Interrupted Transaction
>
> Set a breakpoint in your transaction queue observer’s
>   paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: method so you can control whether it
>   delivers the product. Then make a purchase as usual in the test
>   environment, and use the breakpoint to temporarily ignore the
>   transaction—for example, by returning from the method immediately
>   using the thread return command in LLDB. Terminate and relaunch your
>   app. Store Kit calls the paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: method
>   again shortly after launch; this time, let your app respond normally.
>   Verify that your app correctly delivers the product and completes the
>   transaction.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

To your general question:

`SKPaymentTransaction` provides several transaction states like `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed`
According to the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPaymentTransaction/transactionState) you can check out the `error` property to see what happened. 
For example you can check it in `-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` callback like so

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                ...
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify: how can I *simulate* failed and interrupted transactions?